# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 WLClient.Push.subscribe method not invoked on iOS platform

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a MobileFirst 7.0 hybrid app and I've implemented a notification module for iOS and Android platform.

I am using `WL.Client.Push` API and everything works fine on Android platform with GCM (Android < 6.0 - on Android 6.0 permission policy was changed and now it's very similiar to iOS, but I have not tried on Android 6.0 yet).

I have a problem with iOS. When I try to invoke `WLClient.subscribe` method when first start app on iOS, subscribe method never invoked. I can't find any errors in logs on WAS, I don't see any response from this method- success or failure. I thought that problem is related with permission policy on iOS, because when I click allow for notifications on native popup when app is starting, `subscribe()` method is still not invoked, but when I am logging to the app a second time this method is invoked. But sometimes e.g. on iOS 9.3.1 subscribe method when logging is sometimes invoked and sometimes not :(

I think it's really random for me and I don't know, it's problem with my code, APNS in my country or problem with MobileFirst Push API?

```
RegisterNotifications.doSubscribe = function () {
try{
    WL.Client.Push.subscribe("myPush", {
        onSuccess: doSubscribeSuccess,
        onFailure: doSubscribeFailure
    });
} catch(e){
    //Fix for webbrowser
   //alert("Exception during subscribe to notifications");
    console.log("Exception during subscribe to notifications!");
    EWD.debug("Exception during subscribe to notifications!", "REQUEST_TOP_UP");
}

function doSubscribeSuccess() {
    console.log("You are subscribed successfully!");
    EWD.debug("You are subscribed successfully!","REQUEST_TOP_UP");
   //alert("You are subscribed successfully!");
}

function doSubscribeFailure() {
    console.log("doSubscribeFailure");
    EWD.debug("doSubscribeFailure", "REQUEST_TOP_UP");
   //alert("doSubscribeFailure");
}};

RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed = function() {
var isSubscribed = false;
try{
    if (WL.Client.Push){
        isSubscribed = WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed('myPush');
    }
} catch(e) {
    //Fix for webbrowser
   //alert("RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed: catch" );
}
console.log(isSubscribed);
EWD.debug("RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed: "+ isSubscribed, "REQUEST_TOP_UP");
return isSubscribed;};

RegisterNotifications.isPushSupported = function () {
var isSupported = false;
try {
    if (WL.Client.Push){
        isSupported = WL.Client.Push.isPushSupported();
    }
} catch(e) {
    //Fix for webbrowser
}
EWD.debug("RegisterNotifications.isPushSupported: " + isSupported, "REQUEST_TOP_UP");
console.log(isSupported);
return isSupported;};
if (WL.Client.Push) {
// alert("in try in render WL.Client.Push");
WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function() {
    WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback("myPush",
            "NotificationAdapter", "PushEventSource", pushNotificationReceived);
    EWD.debug("onReadyToSubscribe: you are ready to subscribe user!", "REQUEST_TOP_UP");
    if (RegisterNotifications.isPushSupported()
            && !RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed()) {
        EWD.debug("Now, you can call doSubscribe method!", "REQUEST_TOP_UP");
        RegisterNotifications.doSubscribe();
    }else{
        EWD.debug("Your platform is not supported or you are already subscribed!", "REQUEST_TOP_UP");
    }};} else { EWD.debug("WL.Client.Push loading library problem!", "REQUEST_TOP_UP");}
```

iOS 9.1.0
First time(wi-fi network):

1. RegisterNotifications.isPushSupported() return true
   RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed() return false
   RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed() not invoked, even if I
   click    allow notification on iOS native popup
2. Second time(wi-fi network):  `RegisterNotifications.isPushSupported()`
   return true. `RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed()` return false. 
   `RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed()` invoked, I can send
   notifications for users.

on iOS 9.3.1: completely random, sometimes works sometimes not :(

1. First time(wi-fi network):  `RegisterNotifications.isPushSupported()`
   not invoked. `RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed()` not invoked. 
   `RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed()` not invoked Probably
   `WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe` is never called.
2. Second time(wi-fi network, after kill my app): 
   `RegisterNotifications.isPushSupported()` return true
   `RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed()` return false
   `RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed()` not invoked
3. Third time(wi-fi network, after kill my app):
   `RegisterNotifications.isPushSupported()` return true
   `RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed()` return false
   `RegisterNotifications.isPushSubscribed()` invoked, I can send
   notifications for users.

Comment: Could be a timing issue. 

Could you try out the sample available here :
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/event-source-based-notifications/

and check if that has the same issue?

Comment: Yes, but in this sample user click subscribe button after logged in app. It's not the same issue. I try invoke subscribe method in onReadyToSubscribe  callback. I saw many examples where code is written very similar.

Comment: I understand that. The sample is just to see if there is a problem in iOS 9.3.1 . We have not found an issue yet. Otherwise, like l mentioned earlier, it could be a timing issue

Comment: @KRRySS, any updates in this question?

Comment: Now it works, it was a problem with Apple certificate.